# Moving stream operator >> to the next position

Tags: c++

Say I have a string object called line which contains:

```
Number: 3423
```

and I want to do the following:

```
string keyword;
int number;
stringstream(line) >> keyword >> number;
```

But I only want to extract the number, and am not interested in the keyword.

is there a way of doing this without having to declare a string object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`istream::ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/):

```
stringstream(line).ignore(line.size(), ' ') >> number;
```

Comment: This works for the described case, but not for `line == "  Number: 3423"`

Comment: @Rob Using `':'` for the delimeter should address this problem: `stringstream(line).ignore(line.size(), ':') >> number;`.